# How to display windowless XPS document in a WPF component?

Tags: c#, wpf, xps, documentviewer, windowless

I am currently using DocumentViewer to display an XPS document. It works fine, shows the XPS document in a window, with all the controls: Find on the bottom and Print, Zoom in/out & Page width/height etc on the top.

Is it possible to show just the (windowless) XPS document, without the DocumentViewer controls? Or maybe switch the Find,Print... buttons off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See msdn on styling
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970452.aspx

Comment: Thanks! ControlTemplate was the perfect solution for that